# Is there any way to get a roaming profile in Ubuntu with say ubuntu one, dropbox, rsync, etc?

Tags: dropbox, user-management

Basically my situation is where I jump from machine to machine (about 3 of them) to do development.  I have used [No Machine](http://www.nomachine.com) in addition to [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org) to try and fix my issue. What I basically want is dropbox, ubuntu one, rsync, etc. to sync up all my files as well as config files (parameters for apache, php, mysql, etc).

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Is there something equivalent to portable apps for linux in where things are installed in my local directory then on the other machines I can just use symlinks to point to these files?

I am open to suggestions, it's just a pain having to replicate the same config when I jump machines or having to remote in as I want my local machines processing power for development.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Dropbox and symlinks to every folder in my /home, plus Mozilla sync.

It works very nicely. Dropbox lets me see progress of upload/downloads and with a good connection even medium-sized files travel very quickly from the netbook to the travel laptop to the home desktop to my Android phone and back.

I haven't tried with system config files or with the full /home (I only  have the free smaller Dropbox account), though.

Comment: Does it maintain the symlinks then across machines, or are you saying you are using symlinks on those local machines to point at the synced files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a roaming "development server" configuration a good options is to use some kind of virtualizazion technology (KVM, VBox, VMware,). You would just need to use Dropbox to keep/synch the VM image across systems and make sure the VM software is installed.

Comment: I thought of this, but typically a vm image is large.  I guess I haven't tried setting up my home directory as my dropbox directory but maybe could do that.